# How to kill an activity from a different class?

Tags: android, android-intent

Being relatively new to Android, I guess I didn't word my question properly. Here is what I am trying to do. Generally when you start a new intent, you finish the old activity by using class.this.finish() . But I want to finish a different class, not the current class. Let's say I have an activity with a button. Clicking the button would take me to a second activity. Now clicking another button takes me to a third activity and simultaneously finishes the first activity. Probably finish is the keyword here and not kill.

Comment: Primitive solution: static vars with appropriate checking...

Comment: Hahaha static vars with Activity reference is a stupid idea

Comment: @Selvin: It's a workaround, and dangerous if not used appropriately. It's an ugly solution, I agree, but it is better than none (you didn't write one)...

Comment: Start Activity1 from Activity3 with special flags  with boolean extra in intent ... then in oncreate of Activity1 call finish when intent contain this extra ... i do not remeber which flags should be but there is a lots of similar questions here on SO ...by flags i mean Activity.FLAG_XXXXX

Answer (score 2):

This is a question that doesn't have a straightforward answer. Killing activities is not a good design pattern for Android, so my first thought is "don't do this." Of course, that's not very helpful.

We may be able to help if you describe what you're trying to do. We may be able to suggest an alternative that doesn't requiring killing an Activity, or allows one Activity to finish another in a more "approved" manner.

Sometimes the answer to a problem is to suggest a different problem. Like the robot banging against the wall, the problem is not cutting through the wall, but learning how to turn and go on.

Comment: Being relatively new to Android, I guess I didn't word my question properly. Here is what I am trying to do. Generally when you start a new intent, you finish the old activity by using `class.this.finish()` . But I want to finish a different class, not the current class. Let's say I have an activity with a button. Clicking the button would take me to a second activity. Now clicking another button takes me to a third activity and simultaneously finishes the first activity. Probably `finish` is the keyword here and not `kill`.

Comment: `Generally when you start a new intent, you finish the old activity by using class.this.finish()...` I highly doubt that's a common practice in Android. Activity life cycle is best left for Android to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `BroadcastReceiver` registered in first activity, and send a broadcast from the third activity. Then in `onReceive()` method of the receiver `finish()` the activity.

However, re-thinking the design could be a better solution.

Comment: Bad idea ... you should unregister reciver in Activity onStop ... so if Activity1 isn't the top most it shouldn't have any reciver registered

Comment: @Selvin I agree, that is why I suggested that rethinking the design would be a better solution.